# What is the list comprehension for right triangles in python à la Haskell?

Tags: python, list, haskell, geometry, list-comprehension

In Haskell:

```hs
ghci> let rightTriangles' = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], a <- [1..c], b <- [1..a],
a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a+b+c == 24]

ghci> rightTriangles'
[(6,8,10)]
```

Is there such an elegant list comprehension solution in Python?

Comment: I can't really call this elegant; there is no need to nest the loop 3 times, when the sum equality can be trivially used to constrain one of the variables.

Comment: @wim - true, something like `let rightTriangles'= [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [24 - b - c], a < b, a^2 + b^2 == c^2 ]` would be more efficient, but not necessarily clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a direct translation.

```
[(a, b, c)
 for c in range(1, 11)
 for a in range(1, c + 1)
 for b in range(1, a + 1)
 if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and a + b + c == 24]
```

Comment: And the direct translation of my win-inspired "improvement": `[ (a,b,c) 
  for c in range(1,11)
  for b in range(1, c+1)
  for a in [24 - b - c]
  if a < b and a**2 + b**2 == c**2 ]`

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple syntactic swap:

```
>>> [ (a,b,c) for c in range(1,11)
... for b in range(1,c+1)
... for a in range(1,b+1)
... if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 ]
[(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10)]
```

I skipped your `a+b+c == 24` check, but you could add it if that's what you really need.

Comment: Addressed, though it doesn't affect the output in this case (or any?  not sure about that).

Comment: The range correction allows for the possibility of a=b (isosceles right triangles), though that can never happen when a, b, and c are all integers.